# how to disable 2nd parameter we select 1st parameter in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Please guide how to do this requirement.

I Have a report having 2 command level parameters a and b.
If they select any of the one parameter then other one should be disabled/should not ask any value to enter /should not take any value .
Please suggest how to do

Answer (score 1):

Command don't support optional parameters.  Moreover, you can't disable or hide a parameter based on another parameter's value.

Your best option is to create a parameter that has a default value that will be 'ignored' by the query.

For example, given this Access command:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer 
WHERE region='{?Region}'
```

with this parameter:

[image]

you will note that the parameter's `Optional Prompt` setting is `false` (and not editable):

[image]

Instead, you will need to a default, something like 'ALL' (or -1, in the case of a numeric value):

[image]

Modify the command accordingly:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer 
WHERE ( '{?Region}'='ALL'  OR region='{?Region}' )
```

Comment: Hi Craig  My requirement is somewhat different
I have 2 parameters a and b.
IF user selects a then I should disable b/not giving chance for user to enter any value for  b.
IF user selects b then I should disable a/not giving chance for user to enter any value for  a.
Please suggest

Comment: @user3725135: Crystal Reports doesn't 'support' that requirement.  My solution gives you the best alternative.  If *really* need to dynamically show/hide parameters, then you will need to write a custom application.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a feature of the user interface. You can implement it if you write your own software. The only viewer , which MIGHT be able to do this is R-Tag (www.r-tag.com). But even it will need to do some workaround ( if can do it at all). This behavior is very unique. Why would you need to have it ?

Comment: Hi Lan,  My client request me to do this feature.So that's why

Comment: What are the 2 parameters ?